# Confused by a result of applying the work-energy theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A box is shoved up a plank inclined at an angle $\alpha$ above the horizontal. The plank is covered with ice so that the coefficient of friction is $\mu = Ax$ where $x$ is the distance from the bottom of the plank (in this question the static and kinetic friction are equal). The box's initial speed is $v_0$. I have to show that if the box slides up the plank and comes to rest (without sliding back down), then

$$v_0^2 \ge \frac{3g(\text{sin}\alpha)^2}{A\text{cos}\alpha}.$$

The box's weight is $mg$, we split it into the component down the plank $mg\text{sin}(\alpha)$ and the component normal to the plank $mg\text{cos}(\alpha)$, so the friction force is $Axmg\text{cos}(\alpha)$.

Assuming $v_0$ is large enough, the box will move up a distance $d$ then stop, at this point friction will be equal (and opposite) to the component of weight down the plank, so $mg\text{sin}(\alpha) = Admg\text{cos}(\alpha)$ i.e. $d = \frac{\text{tan}(\alpha)}{A}$.

By the work-energy theorem:

$$0 - \frac{1}{2}mv_0^2 = \int_0^{d} (-mg\text{sin}(\alpha) - Axmg\text{cos}(\alpha)) dx$$

$$\frac{1}{2}v_0^2 = \int_0^{d} (g\text{sin}(\alpha) + Axg\text{cos}(\alpha)) dx = dg\text{sin}(\alpha) + A\frac{d^2}{2}g\text{cos}(\alpha)$$
$$=(1/A)(g\text{sin}^2(\alpha))/(\text{cos}(\alpha)) + g(\text{cos}(\alpha))(1/2)(\text{tan}^2(\alpha))(1/A) = \frac{3g}{2A}\frac{\text{sin}^2(\alpha)}{\text{cos}{(\alpha)}}.$$

I am confused because the work-energy theorem gives $=$ not $\ge$, but $=$ doesn't really make sense because why should $v_0$ be equal to $\frac{3g(\text{sin}\alpha)^2}{A\text{cos}\alpha}?$ How do I deduce that $v_0^2 \ge \frac{3g(\text{sin}\alpha)^2}{A\text{cos}\alpha}?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the calculations that you have performed are calculating the critical value of $v_0$ that would make the block not slide back down.

To get the value as $\ge$, $mg\text{sin}(\alpha) = Admg\text{cos}(\alpha)$ should be replaced with $mg\text{sin}(\alpha) \le Admg\text{cos}(\alpha)$.

But then it would be confusing to actually calculate it that way. so generally, we calculate the critical value and then find if it should be $\ge$ or $\le$.

Generally in physics, there wouldn't be a situation where you can't decide which sign it would be.

Here, we can actually visualize the situation and understand that if the block was given more velocity initially, it slide higher and thus would not be able to come back and deduce that it would be a $\ge$ sign.

Answer (score 1):

In considering μ=Ax, it is pivotal to recognize that μmgcos(α) serves as the upper limit of friction, especially applicable when x≤d. Extending the displacement to x=t introduces μ=At, elevating the frictional force to Atmgcos(α).

However, the noteworthy aspect lies in the adaptive nature of friction. Despite the potential escalation with μ=At, it adeptly aligns itself with mgsin(α), consistently opposing any inclination toward relative motion. Therefore, while the application of the work-energy theorem remains accurate, you need to consider the fact that frictional force at the end will always be same.